# PHP mail() - server error

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to use a simple PHP mail() function to create user feedback from a website. I'm using the 'PHP Secure E-mail' sample script from W3 as a basis. Because of the nature of the email, there's no need for added security or using some of the libraries, e.g. swift mailer, that have been suggested in other posts related to this topic.

When the base form is loaded and the 'send mail' button selected, I get a "server error" message and the following supporting information:

> "The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://www.examplewebsite/formsuccessful.php?forename=Joe&surname=Blogs&email=j.oe.blogs%40example.co.uk&subject=TEST+2&message=Test+Content
>   It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

The file 'formsuccessful.php' file is definitely on the server in the correct folder - unless there's another setting I'm overlooking to enable to this type of PHP scripting?

I've included both the form and PHP code below in case there's an error in those.

Would certainly appreciate some help, I've danced around the houses on this one that many times I can't see the wood from the trees any more.

Cheers.

PHP:

```
<?php
function spamcheck($field)
  {
  $field1=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  if(filter_var($field1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
  {

  $mail = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($mail);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    echo "Invalid input";
    }
  else
    {
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    $name = $_REQUEST['forename']." ".$_REQUEST['surname'];
    mail("admin@examplewebsite.com", "Subject: "$subject,
    "Message: "$message, "From: "$email," ",$name );
    }
  }
else{
    //reload page with message highlighting error
    }
?>
```

HTML Form:

```
<form method="REQUEST" action="formsuccessful.php">
            <fieldset class="master">
            <legend class="master" style="text-align:left;"><b><u>Personal     Details:</u></b></legend>
                <ol class="master">
                    <li class="master"><label class="master"     for"forname">Forename<em class="master">*</em></label><input class="left" type="text"     name="forename" size="30" /></li>
                <li class="master"><label class="master" for"surname">Surname<em class="master">*</em></label><input type="text" name="surname" size="30" /></li>
                <li class="master"><label class="master" for"email">Your Email<em class="master">*</em></label><input type="text" name="email" size="30" /></li>
            </ol>
        <legend class="master" style="text-align: left;"><b><u>Email Contents:</u></b></legend>
            <ol class="master">
                <li class="master"><label class="master" for="subject">Subject:<em class="master">*</em></label><input type="text" name="subject" size="30" /></li>
                <li class="master"><label class="master" for="message">Content:<em class="master">*</em></label><textarea cols="50%" rows="20" onkeyup="checkContent()" name="message" id="message"></textarea></li>
                <li class="master"><input type="submit" value="Send Email" /></li></ol>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Standing by to have the criminally obvious pointed out to me.

Comment: Sorry, let me be a bit more constructive.  How are you serving this website?  The "www.examplewebsite" seems extremely suspect to me.

Comment: Can you put the actual link, where you are testing this script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have some errors here:

```
mail("admin@examplewebsite.com", "Subject: "$subject,
  "Message: "$message, "From: "$email," ",$name );
```

If you want to concatenate, you need to use something like:

```
mail("admin@examplewebsite.com", "Subject: " . $subject,
  "Message: " . $message, "From: " . $email);
```

You also have one parameter too many, I'm not sure what you want to do with the last part `," ", $name` but that's not valid input for the last parameter, see the [manual for `mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: As I said...I was prepared for the blindingly obvious. Thanks a lot...cleared up the parameters and it worked.

Having not had the code working before, I didn't realise it would mark the sender as being the email address recorded in the form - I thought this would simply include the address within the body of the message - hence me trying to concatenate the forename and surnames to the address.

Fixed this by concatenating them to the message instead.

Cheers for the help.

Comment: @dsaa You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your form is using the method "REQUEST" which is not correct it should be GET or POST. 
The php-code that you're using on the other hand seems correct, except for the mail-function which @jeroen already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form method to "post"

Also, i don't think this will make a difference, but use the full URL in the form action.

i.e.: form method="POST" action="http://www.example.com/path/to/file/formsuccessful.php"